# Updating an xml file using linq to xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am trying to update an xml file using the following code from my GUI.

```
var Settings = (from e in config.Descendants("Settings")
                from kvpair in e.Elements("add")
                select new
                {
                    Name = kvpair.Attribute("key").Value,
                    Node = kvpair
                }).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, y => y);

Settings["CustomerA"].Node.Attribute.value=txtCustomerA.Text;
```

The above code works fine:

When i wanted to check whether the key is present in dictionary or not
i am using

```
if(settings.containskey("CustomerA"))
    Settings["CustomerA"].Node.Attribute.value=txtCustomerA.Text;
```

This works fine too.

But i have say 20 entries to be updated i am trying in this fashion inorder to avoid if statement for each udpate

```
Settings["CustomerA"].Node.Attribute.value=settings.containskey("CustomerA") ?txtCustomerA.Text:null;
```

but the above code throws exception the key doesn't exists in the dictionary ???

I was just curious for a work around in order to avoid 20 if statements.I will be glad if some one can guide me.

Comment: I'm assuming all the case irregularities are typos in the reproduction for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a mapping dictionary and loop through it:

```
var mappings = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>
{
    {"CustomerA", () => txtCustomerA.Text},
    {"CustomerB", () => txtCustomerB.Text},
    {"CustomerC", () => txtCustomerC.Text},
    // etc....
};

foreach(var pair in mappings)
{
    Settings[pair.Key] = (Settings.ContainsKey(pair.Key)) ? pair.Value() : null;
}
```

It still really doesn't let you save a lot of coding but it does avoid 20+ `if` statements.